# What is the correct procedure for overwing fueling a CRJ200?

Tags: fuel-systems, refueling, bombardier

I have a question regarding overwing fueling a Canadair CRJ200. Let's say I was pressure fueling and one of the wings started venting fuel on the ground. The Crew Chief determined that I had to overwing fuel the wings, and then finally the center tank.

My question is: exactly how much fuel in gallons can I load into each wing before I should move back to the other wing and start fueling? Meaning, what is safe so that there is no tipping of the aircraft after fueling one wing and then moving to the other to also save time from going back and forth more times than needed to achieve desired amounts in each wing?

Say the Right tank has 2450lbs, the Center tank has 0 and the Left tank also has 2540lbs. I have to start overwing fueling and the pilot's order was for 12,500 lbs total. How many gallons should I start fueling with in (say) the Right wing before I move back to the Left wing and then back to Right again etc.? And then then finish off the Center tank?

Comment: This sounds on first impressions like it should be covered in a manual somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question to (hopefully!) make it more readable but if I got anything wrong then don't hesitate to roll back or edit it again yourself. You might also like to take the [tour] if you're new to StackExchange in general.

Comment: Thank you very much for doing this and hopefully someone can answer this as I have been having a hard time finding out this question of overwing gallon fueling amounts and the aircraft possibly tipping?

Comment: Hopefully someone can answer, but it's very specific and sometimes we just can't answer those questions because no one here knows. If this is a real-life scenario then I guess that you could ask your Crew Chief or another supervisor/manager. After all, if this is part of your job, your employer should make sure that you're trained to handle it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, a pilot had told me that 2500 lb imbalance which equates to 375 gals should be the max to be able to fuel each wing safely before fueling the other side and so on.